# Hide a primary link item for particular user in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, menuitem

I have primary link menu with multiple menu items. I need to implement a "join club" feature and have a primary link item for this purpose.

I need to show this menu item for particular user, e.g., if a user A has an entry in `table5`or in simple words I need to hide menu item on particular `"if"` condition.

What's the way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Menu Per Role module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) to do this. When the user "joins the club" you can (if you don't already) add them to a particular role. If you're not sure how to do this, I can post some instructions but would need some more details about "joining the club".

Once you install the Menu Per Role module, you can control individual menu items to hide or show them based on the user's role. So for your case, use the "Hide menu item from selected roles:" setting on the "Join Club" menu item to hide it from users with the "In the Club" role.